# Python's exe file was quarantined by AVAST, causing my Jupyter Notebook not working

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook

I could not open my Jupyter Notebook since one of the Python's exe file was quarantined by AVAST.

After uninstalling AVAST and installing Norton Security Online, I still can't open Jupyter Notebook. What can I do to fix this issue? I am using Firefox. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Avast quite often messes up builds by quaranting python stuff. I go to the taskbar, right click on the notification, and turn off the scanner till I've finished building.
In the future, the solution will be to find something that doesnt do that at all.